# Check if binary file not Corrupted vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Hi i try to write a code to test if a binary file corrupted or not

```
For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
            ListBox1.SetSelected(i, True)
            Dim name As String = ListBox1.Items.Item(i).ToString
            Try
                Process.Start(name)
                Threading.Thread.Sleep(WaitingTb.Text)
                If Not IsProcessRunning(NameTb.Text) Then
                    MsgBox(name)
                    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(ListBox1.Items.Item(i).ToString)
                    ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i)
                    ListBox1.Items.Insert(i, name & " : Deleted !")
                ElseIf IsProcessRunning(NameTb.Text) Then
                    MsgBox(name)

                    ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i)
                    ListBox1.Items.Insert(i, name & " : Ok !")
                End If
                Process.GetCurrentProcess.Kill()
            Catch
            End Try
        Next
    End Sub
```

IsProcessRunning Function Return true if it find the proccess name else return false

```
Public Function IsProcessRunning(name As String) As Boolean
        'here we're going to get a list of all running processes on
        'the computer
        For Each clsProcess As Process In Process.GetProcesses()
            If clsProcess.ProcessName.StartsWith(name) Then
                'process found so it's running so return true
                clsProcess.Kill()
                Return True
            End If
        Next
        'process not found, return false
        Return False
    End Function
```

sorry for my bad english

Comment: What is the problem? What do you expect to happen? What is happening?

Comment: What do you mean by "Corrupted vb.net" ?

Comment: i try to run a .exe file wait a time like 2 sec check if there is a process name working if there is a listbox got the name and the process killed else delete the .exe and run the nexte .exe